# pdf downloading on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: pdf, download

I have many pdf files on my php page which I want users to be able to download

```html
<a href="form1.pdf" download>Download form1</a>
<a href="form2.pdf" download>Download form2</a>
<a href="form3.pdf" download>Download form3</a>
```

This works on desktop browsers and the downloading works. But when I try to download from mobile browsers the download always fails. How to make it downloadable on all types of devices?

Please help.

Comment: Does your web server pass the correct content-type for PDF? Internet Explorer for example is notorious for guessing content-types if they're not passed correctly, but mobile browsers are generally more picky.

Comment: so how do I pass the correct content-type? desktop Chrome works fine.. but not the mobile Chrome.

Comment: That would greatly depend on your web server and/or if the pdf is passed through a script or just served as a static file by the web server. You can check if the correct content-type is set already by using - for example - fiddler (or curl) and inspecting the headers.

Comment: Furthermore, some browsers require the content length to be given in a header. Some browser/PDF plugin combinations start downloading the PDF multiple times which may or may not be an issue for your web server. Etc. pp.

Comment: Have you tried to define the downloadable filename, like <a href="form1.pdf" download="form1.pdf>Download form1</a> ?